How to find the pool balance at the end of the epoch
I was trying to read pool balance from the end of the epoch and couldn't found any answer yet. My intention is to calculate the APY of given pool public key. I was trying with @solana/web3.js and @solana/spl-stake-pool.

Only the current pool balance is stored on the pool directly, so you would need to fetch the pool before the end of the epoch, and after the start of the next epoch, after the pool has been updated.
To get the pool, you can use the getStakePoolAccount function: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/7d37bd2038adda2f2fb39c86e924dd954d841ff5/stake-pool/js/src/index.ts#L91, and then divide totalLamports by poolTokenSupply, ie:
const prePool = getStakePoolAccount(address);
const preValuePerToken = prePool.account.data.totalLamports.div(prePool.account.data.poolTokenSupply);
// wait for epoch rollover
const postPool = getStakePoolAccount(address);
const postValuePerToken = postPool.account.data.totalLamports.div(postPool.account.data.poolTokenSupply);

const percentChange = postValuePerToken.div(preValuePerToken);

